# Set cronjob script on server

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron, server-side

I'm trying to set up a cronjob script on my server.
 I've followed [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20100414183145/http://www.robotsystematic.com/2009/howto/zend-framework-cron/) tutorial and I now have a folder "scripts" with "**cronjob.php**":

```
<?php
define("_CRONJOB_",true);
require(APPLICATION_PATH . '../public/index.php');

// my executions
?>
```

In my "**index.php**" file:

```
if(!defined('_CRONJOB_') || _CRONJOB_ == false)
{
    $application->bootstrap()->run();
}
```

But how can I set this on my server?
I've done the following as a start: `chmod 755 cronjob.php`, but what's next?

Comment: Did you scroll down to the comments on that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use crontab, make sure you have both crontab and php-cli installed.

First edit the cron by doing

`$ crontab -e`

Then insert something like this

`*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/scripts/cronjob.php`

This examples does execute the script every 10th minute.

For more on the syntax see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Predefined_scheduling_definitions

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method for setting Cron job on Linux Server

Step 1: Open Terminal

Step 2: Type

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

Enter System  Password

Step 3: Put Cron URL to be executed for every 5 minutes interval

```
 */5   *  *   *   *   curl http://testwebsite.com/hitcronscript
```

Reference: https://crontab.guru/every-5-minutes

*Note: For test purpose one may set mail or file/Db entry.

Hope it will help developers.